# Tiling 2 by N rectangle with Tetris shapes

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, geometric-series, tiling

There are similar questions here, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm a physics students and we are asked to prove that using the following 6 shapes, The number of ways to build a 2 by N tiling is $e^{cN}$, we are also asked to find c. Also take into consideration that N goes to infinity. [Here are the available shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y96yq.png). I read some material on this topic and I think recursive relations is the way to go, here is my attempt:

Let $A(N)$ be the number of ways to tile a $2\times N$ rectangle. $A(0)=1$, $A(1)=1$.
We can use two vertical $1\times 1$ rectangles to build a $2\times 2$ tiling, we can use the two combinations of L shapes to build $2\times 3$ tiling, now for $N\geq4$ we can use the L shapes with the vertical rods to build shapes ($2\times 5$ example in the picture). So the recursive relation I proposed is:

\begin{align*}
    A(N) = A(N-1)+A(N-2)+2A(N-3)+2A(N-3)+\cdots+2A(0)
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    A(N) = A(N-1)+A(N-2)+2\sum_{i=0}^{N-3}A(N-3-i)
\end{align*}

Plugging in $A(N)=e^{cN}$, taking $N\to \infty$, and doing the infinite geometric series, I arrive at the equation

\begin{align*}
   e^{3c}-2e^{2c}-1=0
\end{align*}

This equation has one real solution $c\approx0.79$ and two imaginary ones. I think I made a mistake because I shouldn't get imaginary solutions. What seems to be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: $c$ can be complex. The solution $A(N)$ has the form $\sum_{k=1}^3 \lambda_k e^{c_k N}$ where $c_k$ are the three roots of $c$. Assume $\Re c_1 > \Re c_2, \Re c_3$, you will find for large $N$, $A(N)$ is domininated by the term $\lambda_1 e^{c_1 N}$.

Comment: That works for me, but can you explain why the real solution dominates? I'm curios now

Comment: Since $|e^{cN}| = e^{(\Re c)N}$. When $c_1 = \Re c_1 > \Re c_k$, the term $|e^{c_k N}|$ will be smaller than $|e^{c_1 N}|$ by an exponential factor $e^{-(c_1-\Re c_k)N}$. For your case, $c_1 \sim 0.790986$ while $\Re c_2 = \Re c_3 \sim -0.395493$. So the contribution from the complex roots is suppressed by a factor $~e^{-1.18648N}$ wrt that form the real roots.